# How to detect that you reached the last item on android spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to know if I already reached the last item on android spinner because I want to update the array to display new data.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom InfiniteSpinnerAdapter that when [getDropDownView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html#getDropDownView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) is called with last position begins to download new items

Comment: thanks for the fast response. but i wonder how will i know that i already reached the last item. do i need to create a variable that holds the count of the item and check it on getDropDownView if my variable is equal to position?

Comment: The position that is given as parameter on getDropDownView is the position of item that is being created, so basically you need to know how many items you hold currently on the adapter and check that against the loading position, so to answer your question shortly: yes

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to try it.

Comment: Hi, I already  tried what you said. but there is a problem the getDropDownView does not return the last position instantly, instead it returns the indexes of the item  that is being displayed. so what i did is, i automatically add a data to my array when getDropDownView is called but there is also a problem i dont know where to call the notifydatachanged.